# Ubuntu 14.x/LibreOffice 4.2 - How To Print To PS File (not PDF)

Tags: linux, printing, libreoffice, postscript

Not too long ago, one could take an OpenOffice/LibreOffice document under any Linux distro, choose print, and then print the PostScript output to a disk file. This is no longer possible.

Is there any way to install a plain old PostScript driver and pipe the output to disk?

For the avoidance of doubt: I need a true PostScript file with plain ASCII PostScript instructions that can be manipulated from a script. Therefore `pdf2ps` is of no use. It only "PS-ifies" the PDF, but leaves binary data in binary format, which is of no use.

So... to reiterate, I need get the PostScript printer stream from LibreOffice/OpenOffice document and put it in a PostScript file. I have not found such a driver.

All hints/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is also true for Mac OS X: you can now enable or disable *"PDF as the standard print job format"*.

To change it back to PostScript:

1. Open the menu and go to *File -> Preferences... -> LibreOffice -> Print*.
2. Locate the entry *'PDF as standard print job format'*.
3. Make sure this entry does ***NOT*** have the checkbox ticked.
4. Click *'OK'*.

Now the standard print job format should be set back to PostScript.

Here is a screenshot (from LibreOffice 4.4 on OS X):

[image: Setting the LibreOffice print spool format]

Comment: Thanks for this. I had no idea it was there! I thought they had nixed it for good.